# Creating DOM elements using JS with more elements inside

Tags: javascript, html

I've got some tasks to do and I think about how to do it easier.
I have to create (using JS) div element with some class and inside this element I want to create another 2 elements (img src and button) and I'm not sure how to do it.

I can do it like:

```
const newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.classList.add('someClass')
```

after that I can add it to HTML doc and then create another elements (img src and button) and add it to the div I've created before but is there any faster option to create it?

Comment: With *faster* you mean, less typing?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes, if it is even possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way you have created the class, you can create other two elements such as `img` and `button` and make appropriate `src` and `textContent` then using [**appendChild()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), you can append the img and button to the `newElement` which is a parent `div`..

Then finally just append the newly created dom element to `document.body` like,

```
document.body.append(newElement);
```

And the snippet as follows,

```js
const newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.classList.add('someClass');

const image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150');

const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = 'Button';

newElement.append(image);
newElement.append(button);

console.log(newElement);

document.body.append(newElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to build a template in a string. However, this string does not contain instances of elements are simply put; plain text. This means that to modify them, you have to *parse* the string into HTML.

Inserting a string into the document can be done with the [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method. Don't use `innerHTML` because that re-renders the HTML inside the element you append to and could break bindings with event listeners and selectors in your JavaScript.

Here's an example of how this could work.

```js
const getTemplate = (src) => `
  <div class="some-class">
    <img src="${src}" alt="">
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
`;

const template = getTemplate('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
console.log(template);

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);
```

But if you are looking for *best practices*, then go for your original approach en consider accepting Maniraj Murugan's answer.